# PostgreSQL - Handling empty query result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am quite new to SQL and I am currently working on some survey results with PostgreSQL. I need to calculate percentages of each option from 5-point scale for all survey questions. I have a table with respondentid, questionid, question response value. Demographic info needed for filtering datacut is retrieved from another table. Then query is passed to result table. All queries texts for specific datacuts are generated by VBA script.

It works OK in general, however there's one problematic case - when there are no respondents for specific cut and I receive empty table as query result. If respondent count is greater than 0 but lower than calculation threshold (5 respondents) I am getting table full of NULLs which is OK. For 0 respondents I get 0 rows as result and nothing is passed to result table and it causes some displacement in final table. I am able to track such cuts as I am also calculating respondent number for overall datacut and storing it in another table. But is there anything I can do at this point - generate somehow table full of NULLs which could be inserted into result table when needed?

Thanks in advance and sorry for clumsiness in code.

```
WITH ItemScores AS (
SELECT
    rsp.questionid,
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN rsp.respvalue >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) < 5 THEN 
NULL 
ELSE
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN rsp.respvalue = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/CAST(SUM(CASE 
    WHEN rsp.respvalue >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL),2)
END AS 5spercentage,

... and so on for frequencies of 1s,2s,3s and 4s

SUM(CASE WHEN rsp.respvalue >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS QuestionTotalAnswers

FROM (
    some filtering applied here [...]
     ) AS rsp

GROUP BY rsp.questionid
ORDER BY rsp.questionid;
INSERT INTO results_items SELECT * from ItemScores;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ensure that the `questionid` column won't be empty, then you must call a cte with its plain values and then `left join` with the table that actually you are using to make the aggregations, calcs etc. So it will generate for sure the first list and then join its values.

The example of its concept would be something like:

```
with calcs as (
select questionid, sum(respvalue) as sum_per_question
from rsp
group by questionid)

select distinct rsp.questionid, calcs.sum_per_question
from rsp
left join calcs on rsp.questionid = calcs.questionid
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Julinho for this concept - it works for me :).